# Is the verb "taked" right?

Tags: verb-forms, irregular-forms

Do you use the verb "taked" to mean the past of the verb "take" or the p.p. form of it?

For example is it right to say:

1. I taked an exam yesterday. instead of I took an exam.
2. I have taked an exam. instead of I have taken an exam.

Comment: These kind of questions always intrigue me: _why_ do you think said form would be correct? I suppose something triggered you into thinking it might be correct; why not share that with us? Without that context, this question feels almost as if you made up a word and wondered if by any chance you discovered an existing one :)

Answer (score 24):

No, [*take*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/take) is an irregular verb:

- Its past tense form is *took*:

  > I **took** an exam yesterday.
- Its past participle form is *taken*:

  > I **have taken** an exam.

**Taked* is nonstandard.  You may occasionally hear it from young children or in certain nonstandard dialects, but if you're learning Standard English you should not say it yourself.

Comment: +1. Note that *taked* can sometimes occur in certain colloquial compounds, such as *spit-taked* (meaning "did a [spit-take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spit-take)"); \**spit-took* or \**spit-taken* would not be grammatical. (But this is not to suggest that all speakers would accept *spit-taked*, either. I think most speakers would prefer the circumlocution "did a spit-take", using the noun *spit-take* rather than the verb.)

Comment: I've never seen spit-take used as a verb.

Comment: @SamuelLijin: I don't think I have either, but I would probably recognize the intended meaning. There aren't a whole lot of phrases involving "take" that could be used as verbs, but I think it's good to explain the principle that coined verbs phrases, especially when hyphenated, often do not use the same conjugations as the verbs comprising them.

Comment: The notion of *spit-take* as a verb just made me spray coffee all over my laptop... ;-)

Comment: There is a general tendency for verbs which are formed from nominal phrases to be regular, even when the phrase contains a strong verb. PInker discusses this in _The Language Instinct_, and argues it is because the phrases in question are "headless".

Answer (score 1):

"Taked" is an incorrect spelling and it doesn't exist in English. You should use Took or Taken for past tense and past participle form.

Comment: What does this add to the other answer, which was posted five hours earlier?

Comment: double confirmation

Comment: You can indicate your agreement with the other answer by voting it up.